# Trying to run Security Onion on AWS behind an ALB (nginx behind ALB)

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, security, amazon-alb

I've got a wildcard certificate for internal services. I'd like to run Security Onion behind an ALB so I can get valid SSL with a single certificate stored in certificate manager. (Storing it there is better for security as well as easier maintenance and reliability)

The problem seems to be that in the Security Onion config file
/opt/so/saltstack/local/pillar/global.sls

```
url_base: # IP or FQDN
```

Can EITHER be configured to listen by IP address (at which point the login redirects point at IP and verified SSL breaks) OR by FQDN (at which point it doesn't answer requests by IP and the target group health check fails).

I accidentally got it working by flipping from IP to FQDN. But I suspect it was working in the 2min grace period while the healthcheck was still green but the server was working by FQDN.

Behind the scenes Security Onion is using nginx to perform host to docker routing.
The nginx config file is here
/opt/so/saltstack/default/salt/nginx/etc/nginx.conf

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by inserting a simple healthcheck in the nginx config.

```
server {
              listen 443 ssl http2;
              server_name 192.168.1.something;
              location /health {
                  access_log off;
                  add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
                  return 200 "healthy\n";
             }
         }
```

Two limitations of this approach.

1. I hardcoded the IP address in my config and this will break if my host ever moves or gets re-instantiated from snapshot. (Can this be fixed by having nginx infer the local IP?)
2. The healthcheck verifies that nginx is running but not that SO is healthy behind it.